# Macbook pro 8,1 skype audio

Tags: audio, macintosh, skype

I cannot seem to get skype to use my microphone on this macbook pro 8,1.

I've used alsamixer to set all speaker/mic setting to unmute with max volume, nothing. (although when I set the "digital" channel to max there is a loud hissing).

The macbook has some strange quirks in it's audio setup. Most devices double for both input and output (eg the mini-jack is both headphone output and mic input). This is why I fear for the worst.

Has anyone been able to get it working?

Comment: Do you have Linux or Mac OS X on Macbook?

Comment: woops forgot to mention: Arch Linux with skype from AUR.